# Равнораспределенное вычитание. Простая задачка.

Tags: алгоритм

Есть 3 числа (на самом деле их может быть не одна сотня, это для примера), например

10, 80, 10

В сумме они должны быть равны 100, могут быть дробными.
Если первое увеличить на 10, то оно будет 20

20, x, y

x и y в сумме должны значит быть равны 80, а соотношение конечных чисел x и y должно сохраниться.

Comment: если куда-то что-то добавляем, значит откуда-то что-то надо отнять?)
я не совсем понял как это должно работать, но если ты к (10) + 10, то с остальных надо отнять 10, или рандомно считать число, которое ты хочешь отнять, но что бы они в сумме не превышали 10

Comment: соотношение x и y чисел должно сохраниться

Answer (score 2):

Так не пойдёт (с использованием библиотеки gmp)?

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    vector<mpq_class> v;
    stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    mpq_class add, sum = 0, ratio;
    vector<mpq_class>::iterator i;
    getline(cin, str);
    ss.str(str);
    while(!ss.eof()) {
        mpq_class w;
        ss >> w;
        v.push_back(w);
    }
    v.pop_back(); // почему-то вводится лишнее число
    cin >> add;
    for(i = v.begin() + 1; i != v.end(); i++) sum += *i;
    ratio = (sum - add)/sum;
    cout << v[0] + add;
    for(i = v.begin() + 1; i != v.end(); i++) cout << ' ' << *i * ratio;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Трансляция `g++ jkeks.c++ -lgmpxx -lgmp`  Если не использовать gmp, то рациональные числа можно реализовать парами целых (надо только написать operator>>, operator<< и сокращение дробей). Использование float/double чревато ошибками округления в случае периодических дробей (знаменатель не является степенью двойки).
Для примера `10 80 10` ответ `20 640/9 80/9`

Comment: вах.. как умно, я нашел решение уже, оно оказалось однострочным и красивым, сначала вычислим коэфициент на разнице сумм сотавшихся,а затем умножим оставшиеся на него. Правда мне помог один тоже чел.

Comment: А привести красивое решение не судьба?

Comment: @jkeks, ratio и есть тот самый коэффициент.

Просто код достаточно неочевиден, по крайней мере на мой взгляд:) Например с первого взгляда не понятно, что sum это сумма всех элементов кроме первого. А еще пользователю может захотеться прибавлять не к первому элементу, а к какому-нибудь другому)